# I get this error in Xcode: @interface for 'AppDelegate' declares the selector 'performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I get this error in `Xcode`: `@interface` for `AppDelegate` declares the selector `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:`.

My `main.storyboard` has a seque from the regular view to the one for the first launch.

My `AppDelegate.m` says this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"])
    {
        // app already launched
        NSLog(@"this app has already been launched partner");
    }
    else
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        // This is the first launch ever
        NSLog(@"first time launch bb");
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toWelcomeScreen" sender:self];


    }
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}
```

How do I make it so on the first launch, it shows the view with segue `toWelcomeScreen`?

Comment: App delegate can not perform the segues. View controllers do so put your segue code inside the "home"view controller to display "welcome" view controller

Comment: How do I make it detect if it is the first launch in the ViewController? I only know how in the AppDelegate.

Comment: The same way you are doing it in the appdegate .. Use     if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"])

Comment: I now get: clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 2):

`-performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` is not a method defined in the `<UIApplicationDelegate>` protocol, therefore it cannot be called on `self` in this context. Subclasses of `UIViewController` can respond to the message `-performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:`, so call this on the `AppDelegate`'s `window`'s `rootViewController` property.

```
[self.window.rootViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toWelcomeScreen" sender:self];
```

Make sure you have assigned a `rootViewController` before this call.
**Edit:** `rootViewController` is a property of the the `AppDelegate`'s window.

[image]

**Edit 2:** to assign the `rootViewController` property, just set it to an instance of your custom view controller.

```
self.window.rootViewController = [[MyCustomViewControllerThatIWantToSegueTo alloc] init];
```

Comment: That returns "property 'rootViewController' not found on object of type 'AppDelegate *'" EDIT: How do I assign that?

Comment: self.window.rootViewController